# Activate RPI-cam with rfid signal

Tags: camera, rfid

Can anyone give me some advice on the next.
Is it possible to activate the RPI-cam with a signal from a rfid reader?

Here's the practical enviroment.
I am a pigeon fancier and my pigeons are registered by a rfid reader. I would like to have a picture of the arrived pigeon on the moment he/she steps on the rfid reader. This picture has to be send to an external server.

Can anyone help me out or give me some tips. I am a newby to RPI.

Kind regards

Gerard

Comment: RFID-marked pigeons is the first step to the sharks with the laser beams =)

Comment: you have a camera? usb or raspicam? do you have the rfid reader? you have program experience?

Answer (score 1):

The RPi educational materials include a short workshop on [using the camera module](http://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/python-picamera-setup/). Part of this ("Camera programming: Capture when activated") demonstrates wiring and code to take a picture in response to an external button being pushed.

On the RFID side of things, it looks like the amusingly named [RFIDIOt library](https://github.com/AdamLaurie/RFIDIOt) is something that would enable Python to talk to several RFID readers.

So, assuming you have a RFID reader that you can connect to the Pi (and which is compatible with RFIDIOt), it shouldn't be terribly difficult to modify the recipe to your purposes: replace `GPIO.wait_for_edge` with some code that waits for a valid RFID token, e.g. `card.select()` and you should be well on your way. You'll probably find there's a bit of fine-tuning to do (you may have to implement some form of debounce - I'm not familiar enough with RFID to know if this is an issue), and of course the script needs modifying to continually wait and take pictures instead of stopping after the first one.